# Nuxeo web-ui and the jsf interface at the same time

Tags: nuxeo, dam

Is it possible to install nuxeo web-ui and the jsf interface at the same time ?
the web-ui looks experimental but promising, as I'm new to nuxeo I thought I'll give it a go over the classic interface, though:
- Couldn't find the full admin interface in the web-ui
- Wasn't able to create a workspace from a template in web-ui

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes both user interfaces can be installed at the same time, just install both packages.

Comment: How to access each of them separetly then, going to host/nuxeo goes directly to host/nuxeo/ui/ the new interface

Comment: Use `nuxeo/jsf` to go to the JSF UI.